# Coding projects for LAMP stack locally

Tags: apache2, php, lamp

I've got a LAMP stack up and running (lamp-server^ specifically), and now I'd like to experiment a bit with it, although I would rather not be editing files in `/var/www/html`, it seems silly to be doing everything as root.

Is there a good way to code projects somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, enable the `userdir` module for Apache (I'm unfamiliar with lamp-server, normally you just run `sudo a2enmod userdir` but you'll have to figure out how to enable the module).

Once enabled, you can create a `public_html` directory inside your home, ensure your home and `public_html` have world read permissions, and you can put your PHP scripts in your `public_html`.

Optionally, you could add your user to the `www-data` group and make `/var/www/html` group-writable (`sudo chmod g+w /var/www/html`).

Either approach is suitable for testing and development, for production I suggest you google around for current best PHP practice, as I'm way too rusty to suggest anything specific.

Answer (score 0):

Open your `httpd.conf` file. It's usually under `~\etc\httpd.conf`. There you will find a line like this

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
<Directory "/var/www/html">
```

Change it to your desired path and restart the server. It should solve your problem..